# How to say "I have been ～ for X months"

Tags: meaning, particle-に

> Nihongo ha kyuu kagetsu ni benkyou shiteiru
>   = I've been studying japanese for 9 months.

If it's wrong, why? Should it be "kyuu kagetsu go ni?"

Comment: Basically [we can't answer "Is this correct?" questions](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010). Please focus on one thing per question and use an appropriate title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather say: 私は九ヶ月間、日本語を勉強しています。(Watashi ha kyuukagetsu kan nihongo wo benkyoushiteimasu).

In this case of a continued action in time  you do not need at all the particle に after the word indicating how much time you have been doing something. Add instead 間 (kan) that indicates a span/length of time. Also, を (wo) should mark the object/what is that you are studying (in this case Japanese).

Actually, there is a related question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19148/how-do-you-say-i-have-been).